# Unable to run bcp command from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, bcp

I have to call `bcp.exe` from a PowerShell script. My code is:

```
$dataBase = 'MyDb'
$ProdEinheitTable = 'dbo.ProdEinheit'
$ProzessdatenTable = 'dbo.Prozessdaten_aktuell'
$sqlServerUserName = 'sa'
$sqlServerPassword = 'Password'
$server = 'MSSQLLocalDB'

$bcp = & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
```

and I am calling the `bcp` utility like this:

```
$bcp_args = "$bcp $dataBase.$ProdEinheitTable IN $datFileName -f $fmtFileName -U $sqlServerUserName -P sqlServerPassword -S $server -n"
Invoke-Expression $bcp_args
```

It gives me the error

```
usage: : The term 'usage:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ usage: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe { ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (usage::String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I remove `&` from the string I get the exception

```
C:\Program : The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe MyDb.dbo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I call `bcp` from PowerShell?

Comment: I would try to use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) with `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Comment: [Do not use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work the way you expect (aside from the fact that you [shouldn't be using `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) in the first place) is because your expectation seems to be that

```
$bcp = & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
```

would define some kind of command invocation alias. That is not the case. The statement directly invokes `bcp.exe` without arguments and stores the *output* of the command in the variable `$bcp` (regular output, not error output).

This should work:

```
$dataBase = 'MyDb'
$ProdEinheitTable = 'dbo.ProdEinheit'
$ProzessdatenTable = 'dbo.Prozessdaten_aktuell'
$sqlServerUserName = 'sa'
$sqlServerPassword = 'Password'
$server = 'MSSQLLocalDB'

$bcp = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'

$bcp_args = "${dataBase}.${ProdEinheitTable}", 'IN', $datFileName,
            '-f', $fmtFileName, '-U', $sqlServerUserName,
            '-P', $sqlServerPassword, '-S', $server, '-n'

& $bcp @bcp_args
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
$bcp = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
$bcp_args = "$dataBase.$ProdEinheitTable IN $datFileName -f $fmtFileName -U $sqlServerUserName -P sqlServerPassword -S $server -n"

Start-Process -FilePath $bcp -ArgumentList $bcp_args
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with the call operator like here with an array for the args that somehow works right:  https://com2kid.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/powershell-call-operator-using-an-array-of-parameters-to-solve-all-your-quoting-problems/

```
$bcp = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
$bcp_args = echo $bcp $dataBase.$ProdEinheitTable IN $datFileName -f $fmtFileName -U $sqlServerUserName -P sqlServerPassword -S $server -n
& $bcp $bcp_args
```